# Criar x quantidade de <li> de acordo com variavel $paginas em php

Tags: php

Tenho uma variavel $paginas que traz a quantidade de páginas.

Aí preciso que pra cada página ele crie uma li, ex:

```
$paginas = 3;
sairia o resultado:
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um laço de repetição `for`, enquanto o contador for menor que a quantidade de páginas um, `li` é impresso com o valor, comecei o contador em 1 para a lista iniciar também iniciar no número 1.

```
$paginas = 3;

for($i = 1; $i <= $paginas; $i++){
    echo "<li>$i</li>";
}
```